# Can someone explain why the program shows me 6 and 4?

Tags: c++

In this problem,which is an easy and a simple one, i do the sum and the product. I wanted to do with a "for" instruction to understand how this thing is working.

```
#include < iostream >
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,i,s=0,p=1;
    cin>>n;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
         s=s+i;
         p=p*i;

        cout<<s<<" "<<p;
}
```

I can't explain why the result is "6" for sum and "4" for product...

Can someone explain me why the code is showing this?
If i put the instructions from the "for" structure between of braces,it is showing "6" for sum and "6" for product.

Comment: Do you understand that `p=p*i;` is outside of the loop?

Comment: stepping through the code with a debugger would be helpful

Comment: Another thing that would be helpful would be specifying the actual input given to the program.

Comment: If you don't put brackets around the code then the compiler will only execute the first line, then second one will be out of the for loop scope.

Comment: Indentation in `c++` does not make the code part of the same block. You need to tell the compiler with `{` and `}`

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. GCC for example has a very nice warning that "indentation is misleading", when you forget about brackets.

Comment: OK,but why at product the result is "4" if n=3?

Comment: The loop will be left, when `i == 4`. Since `p=p*i;` is outside of the loop and `p` was initialized with `1`, the new value will be `p = 1 * 4`. You really should learn how to use your debugger. It's one of the most important tools for developers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not `< iostream >`, it's `<iostream>`. White space is not allowed there. Second of all, despite the indentation, `p=p*i;` is outside the `for` loop. [Turn on compiler warnings](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0KSKK5m78BsOXHlj):

```
prog.cc:7:5: warning: this 'for' clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
    7 |     for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
      |     ^~~
prog.cc:9:10: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the 'for'
    9 |          p=p*i;
      |          ^
```

Use `{}` to fix this:

```
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
         s=s+i;
         p=p*i;
}
```